# ¿Cómo imprimo un número con un 0 a la izquierda?

Tags: bash

Quiero sumar dos variables en bash:

```
var1=01 y var2=02.
```

Cuando hago la suma me devuelve un `3`, y quisiera que me saque un `03`

¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo he definido

```
number=3
```

si lo imprimo con echo:

```
echo $number
=> 3
```

si lo imprimo con printf:

```
printf "%'02d\n" $number
=> 03
```

Comment: Funciona! Muchas gracias!!